# Match entire statement in Elastic Search

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to match whole statement while querying in Elastic search. But not able to achieve it right.

```
"query": {
            "match_phrase": {"description": query_tokens}
        }
```

I tried with `Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner`, but it provided me result like general match query.
How should i achieve complete statement fetch?

Comment: I am so thankful for your answer. Unfortunately this is not the solution to my problem, else i definitely would have definitely up-voted.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Store these statement(description field) in the `keyword field`.

**Reason of not working**

Match phrase query is analyzed which means the same analyzer which used at index time, used as query time to create search tokens and by default for `text` field it's [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) which breaks tokens on space and `,` id special char.

**Statement from Elasticsearch doc**

> The match_phrase query analyzes the text and creates a phrase query
>   out of the analyzed text. For example:

**Index Def**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "description": 
            {
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample doc**

```
{
  "description" :   "Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner"
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "description" : {
                "query" : "Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "match",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "description": "Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks a'lot for your help, unfortunately even by using query keyword, its same result... I was hoping to find someway in which at least it covers entire statement and more.

Comment: @TrickOrTreat, sorry I didn't understand, can you update your question with more samples so I can understand better, and whats the issue with sample I used ?

Comment: its also fetching `Air flow Air flow` , `Air pump Air pump`, why is it fetching such statements when it does not contain `Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner`? I am looking for strict statement search,

Comment: @TrickOrTreat, now its quite clear, l'll fix that as well :)

Comment: No problem.. Is there way to achieve this..?

Comment: I just tried this on my fresh index by using the mapping I posted in my answer and indexed 3 sample docs in your comment , searching for `Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner` returns me only 1 doc using the same search query in my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213141/discussion-between-opster-elasticsearch-ninja-and-trickortreat).

Comment: i cannot chat, because of company restrains. I tried `{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "description" : {
                "query" : "Air Conditioning, Air Conditioner"
            }
        }
    }
}`
Something else should i add..?

Comment: And you are searching on both fields??

Comment: only one field 'description' is present, So i want to search minimum entire statement which i am giving as query.

Comment: @TrickOrTreat, I am not sure, why it's not working for you? can you share your requests in a postman collection, so that I can try them?

Comment: @Also which version of ES ?

Comment: I am using latest version only

Comment: hmm its really difficult, can you chat now?

Comment: @TrickOrTreat, can you upload your entire sample on github or proviude the postman collection, so I can debug your issue?

Comment: i really can't upload whole data but in short idea is to search the query with words in same order. Suppose if i am searching for 'somthing here in vehicle' then it should be able search entire statement

Comment: Its already covered in my answer, not sure why you are not getting it.

Comment: @TrickOrTreat, any luck or u are still blocked?

Comment: yeah... i am still blocked over this. Searching exact statement is still a problem to me. However requirement got changed a bit, so m loose. I would anyway appreciate an answer...